# Best way to recover/restore Time Machine Backup to a second HD?

Tags: time-machine, backup

My Macbook HD got corrupted and it couldn't be repaired. Being a 2011 Macbook model, I decided to buy a SSD to be the primary HD and a second 1TB to be used instead of cdrom (using a kit from [maxupgrades](http://www.maxupgrades.com/istore/index.cfm?fuseaction=product.display&Product_ID=186)).

So far, so good. Problem is: now I want to recover/restore a Time Machine backup to this new 1TB hard disk (that isn't the primary one). Which is the best way to avoid data loss in the process? Can I just copy the files from /Backups.backupdb/Latest?

Comment: I’m not understanding if you want to clone data from one time machine destination to another new time machine disk or just load from time machine to a running os. Is this about either of the above fidderent taks or something else you seek to do. Basically, what end result are you seeking?  I’m pretty sure both can be done which makes existing answer not correct

Answer (score -2):

Well... the answer when you posted this question WAS yes.  You could just turn off auto-backups and copy the backups folder to a new drive and set Time Machine's prefs to use that drive.

But if you've migrated to Mojave, good luck. Apple has seen fit to remove that ability from even an admin's hands.  You don't have the ability to modify the Backups.backupdb folder or contents, even with SIP disabled.

EDIT: I think I found a workaround.  You can't modify Backups.backupdb, but you can delete it and replace it.  Back up your backups, if you feel the need.  Create a folder named "WhosTheBoss" or "ImTheBoss" and put any backups that you want to keep in there (with the same directory structure).  Delete the original Backups.backupsdb folder and make that the name of "WhosTheBoss".  Point Time Machine and/or Migration Assistant to that location and you're good to go.